# In Codeigniter how to perform POST request through ngrok?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ngrok

I have a site (using Codeigniter 3.1.10) which is working fine while accessing through localhost. I am trying to test it by accessing it through ngrok, i.e. from another remote system through internet. Through ngrok I am able to access the login page as:

```
 http://f94181a4.ngrok.io/mysite/logincontroller/login
```

This displays the login view. However, when I clicked the submit button in the login view/page, it sends POST request as below from the remote systems browser:

```
http://localhost/mysite/logincontroller/loginaction
```

Since the remote system is requesting it as http://localhost, it is not able to connect to my local server. So how will I make it to send the POST request with  http://f94181a4.ngrok.io when requested from remote system browser.

```
http://f94181a4.ngrok.io/mysite/logincontroller/loginaction
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ngrok, but I suppose this is a `base_url` issue. In ngrok if you `<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>` does it give you `http://f94181a4.ngrok.io`? if so you could probably switch out the static base url for that php line

Comment: You probably forgot to set "base_url" config to the new one.

Comment: @Alex I am not sure where I need to add that piece of code. However I tried adding on the loginView. It gives http://f94181a4.ngrok.io. And how to modify the static base url. As of now I dont set any base_url  i.e. $config['base_url'] = '';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to set "base_url" config.

Try to change to this

```php
$protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https" : "http";
$config['base_url'] = "$protocol://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/mysite/";
```

Comment: Actually, I didnt set any base_url as of now i.e. $config['base_url'] = '';. When I set it as you provided, it redirects to XAMPP dashboard. What else do I need to modify?

Comment: @Angom you have to add "mysite/" in the end of `base_url` config.